# streams with default utf8 handling

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11, stream, locale

I have read that in some environments `std::string` internally uses UTF-8. Whereas, on my platform, Windows, `std::string` is ASCII only. This behavior can be changed by using `std::locale`. My version of STL doesn't have, or at least I can't find, a UTF-8 facet for use with strings. I do however have a facet for use with the `fstream` set of classes.

Edit:
When I say "use UTF-8 internally", I'm referring to methods like `std::basic_filebuf::open()`, which in some environments accept `UTF-8` encoded strings. I know this isn't really an `std::string` issue but rather some OS's use `UTF-8` natively. My question should be read as "how does your implementation handle code conversion of invalid sequences?".

How do these streams handle invalid code sequences on other platforms/implementations?

In my `UTF8` `facet` for files, it simply returns an error, which in turn prevents any more of the stream from being read. I would have thought changing the error to the Unicode "Invalid char" 0xfffd value to be a better option.

My question isn't limited to `UTF-8`, how about invalid `UTF-16` surrogate pairs?

Let's have an example. Say you open a `UTF-8` encoded file with a `UTF-8` to `wchar_t` `locale`. How are invalid `UTF-8` sequences handled by your implementation?
Or, a `std::wstring` and print it to `std::cout`, this time with a lone surrogate.

Comment: It depends on the use case. Sometimes you want errors to be signaled (when invalid data is totally unacceptable); sometimes you want U+FFFD; sometimes you want to simply discard the bad data; sometimes you want something else.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Does your implementation at least give you the option of telling it how to handle such situations?

Comment: In your example - please can you give the exact codecvt facet ? is it : `std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>` ? - what exact stream are you using ? `std::wifstream` ? What exact string type do you plan on using ? `std::wstring` or `std::string` ?

Comment: @IwanAucamp I don't have the C++11 extensions for those facets. Although I do have a `std::codecvt< char32_t, char, mbstate_t >` facet which is only for file streams.

Comment: @Waldermort so which are you using ?

Comment: @IwanAucamp That would be `basic_filebuf< char32_t >` with the above mentioned `codecvt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say you open a UTF-8 encoded file with a UTF-8 to wchar_t locale. How are invalid UTF-8 sequences handled by your implementation?

Typically no one bothers with converting to `wchar_t` or other wide char types on other platforms, but the standard facets that can be used for this all signal a read error that causes the stream to stop working until the error is cleared.

Comment: As far as I can gather from the standard this is the required behavior.

Answer (score 4):

> I have read that in some environments std::string internally uses uses UTF-8.

A C++ program can chose to use `std::string` to hold a UTF-8 string on any standard-compliant platform.

> Whereas, on my platform, Windows, std::string is ASCII only.

That is not correct.  On Windows you can use a `std::string` to hold a UTF-8 string if you want, `std::string` is not limited to hold ASCII on any standard-compliant platform.

> This behavior can be changed by using std::locale.

No, the behaviour of `std::string` is not affected by the locale library.

A `std::string` is a sequence of `chars`.  On most platforms, including Windows, a `char` is 8-bits.  So you can use `std::string` to hold ASCII, Latin1, UTF-8 or any character encoding that uses an 8-bit or less code unit.  `std::string::length` returns the number of code units so held, and the `std::string::operator[]` will return the ith code unit.

For holding UTF-16 you can use `char16_t` and `std::u16string`.

For holding UTF-32 you can use `char32_t` and `std::u32string`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` should be encoding agnostic: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string - so it should not validate codepoints/data - you should be able to store any binary data in it.

The only places where encoding really makes a difference is in calculating string length and iterating over string character by character - and locale should have no effect in either of these cases.

And also - use of `std::locale` is probably not a good idea if it can be avoided at all - its not thread safe on all platforms or all implementations of standard library so care must be taken when using it. The effect of this is also very limited, and probably not at all what you expect it to be.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and is unrelated, and wrong. The effects of `locale` are very clear and even required in most stream handling operations.

Comment: @Waldermort No, it's not wrong - `std::string` indeed does not know or care about character encodings at all. It does not have an "internal encoding". It's very much a container of bytes - for instance, `std::string::length()` always returns the number of bytes, not the number of characters.

Comment: @JohannesD I wasn't asking about `std::string` but rather it's under the hood handling of character encodings. Also, while you are technically correct, you don't take into account `wstring` or the C++11 16/32 bit strings, which do not return the number of bytes ;)

Comment: @Waldermort `std::string` has no 'under the hood' handling of encodings. And your question doesn't ask anything about `std::wstring` or `char16_t` or `char32_t` strings.

Comment: @bames53 Are you sure? What is the `std::locale`, which has a `std::codecvt` facet, used for? Is that not encoding? And my question relates to `streams` in general, not only `strings`.

Comment: @Waldermort Yes, `std::string` does not use the locale at all. `std::codecvt` is used by some streams but the default `std::codecvt<char,char,std::mbstate_t>` is a no-op converter; it just passes bytes along without doing anything. The console chooses how it wants to handle invalid sequences it's asked to display.

Comment: @Waldermort `string`s aren't `stream`s

Comment: @Waldermort - sorry for not elaborating more on streams, I'm actually unsure that your problem is related to validation - from your question it seems your file is utf8 - and the string is utf8 - so if no conversion is happening everything should just work out. Can you maybe give us a sample program and sample input file (uuencoded will be helpful for the input file so that test can be done with exact data).

Comment: @IwanAucamp Just updated the question with an example. Sure, if no code conversion is happening, it's just a pass through, but for things like `std::is_numeric` which uses the `locale` and actual conversions, it's implementation specific.